# (Angular4 / TypeScript) How to Bind Component @Input Property to View?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to display a component input property in view?

I've tried several ways, including this, but none has been working: https://ngdev.space/angular-2-input-property-changes-detection-3ccbf7e366d2

*Component usage:*

```
<card [title]='My Awesome Card'></card>
```

*Template:*

```
<div class="ui card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">{{ title }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Part of component declaration:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html'
})

export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  private _title: string;

  get title(): string {
    return this._title;
  }

  @Input()
  set title(title: string) {
    console.log('prev value: ', this._title);
    console.log('got title: ', title);
    this._title = title;
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strings can be binded into `@Input` property like below

```
<card [title]="'My Awesome Card'"></card>
```

Comment: @envision sorry it's a mistake. updated answer , hope it may help

Comment: That was it, I needed to bind *a string* ...thank you very much @Rajez

Answer (score 1):

I see there are 2 errors

***passing string literal***
`<card [title]="'My Awesome Card'"></card>` - As you are passing string not a variable pass in between quotes.

***@Input*** - when data passed to child it need to be a @Input variable not function. you need to declare variable as @Input

```
@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html'
})

export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() _title: string;

  get title(): string {
    return this._title;
  }

  set title(title: string) {
    console.log('prev value: ', this._title);
    console.log('got title: ', title);
    this._title = title;
  }
```

Comment: Those are getters/setters, not "functions" and yes you can use the @Input decorator on them. See the link provided by the OP.

Comment: Nice to know that. I never used @Input() on setter or getter. :)

Comment: That's one of the really great things about hanging out here ... its a great opportunity to see how other devs do things differently so we can learn so much more! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In component declaration part, we can just pass input variable as below-

> @Input() title: string = "My Awesome Card";

or

> @Input() title: string